# How to replace url of taxonomy label link?

Tags: 8

I want to alter url of a field and his display.
The field is a taxonomy label with link to the entity.
The default url is : `taxonomy/term/{tid}`

I wanto to chage with : `my_specific_page?technologie={tid}` (used to prepopulate exposed filter)

I tried with :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field__field_technologie(&$variables, $hook){
  $element = $variables['element'];

  foreach ($variables['items'] as $item) {

    $route_name = 'entity.node.canonical';
    $params     = 39;

    $options = [
      'query' => ['technologie' => 27],
    ];
    $url = Url::fromRoute($route_name, array('node' => $params), $options);

    $item['content']['#url'] = $url;
  }
}
```

I think i need to replace routeName attribut, but how ?

Content type : "manage field"
[image: Content type : "manage field"]
Content type : "manage display"
[image: Content type : "manage display"]
Kint result $variables['element']
[[image: kint]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjzAf.png)

Comment: I can't get the point, can you improve a little the question?

Comment: Ok, I added pictures and changed the title for more understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution :

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field__field_technologie(&$variables, $hook){
  $element = $variables['element'];

  foreach ($variables['items'] as $index => $item) {

    $route_name = 'entity.node.canonical';
    $params     = 39;
    $tid = $item['content']['#options']['entity']->id();

    $options = [
      'query' => ['technologie' => $tid],
    ];

    $url = Url::fromRoute($route_name, array('node' => $params), $options);
    $variables['items'][$index]['content']['#url'] = $url;
  }
}
```